How to send email from groovy post build plugin?
We have a use case where we want to fetch some specific messages from jenkin console logs when build gets fail. We want to trigger the email if the failure message matches with our expected one.
As we have to apply this change on 3000+ jobs (freestyle mostly), we want to use post groovy plugin for it. However, we are not able to send email from it.
Any alternate easy suggestion would also be appreciated.
We have below plugins with us :

Groovy post build
Flexible publish
Email ext


What do you mean "not able"? Any specific error message?

Do you have a script which can send email from post groovy plugin (not declarative or scripted) with emailExt? even the AI suggested script doesn't work.

RROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.emailext() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[mimeType:text/html, replyTo:abc@gmail.com, subject:hello, ...]]

Groovy postbuild script doesn't have access to pipeline steps and runs in a sandbox, so to send an email you would have to add some email library to the script classpath and allow a bunch of methods in ScriptSecurity

can we use the mailer plugin?

The email-ext plugin has a customizable trigger that has access to build log. It sounds like this might do what you need. Add it as a post-build action and in Advanced settings add a Script - After Build as a trigger.
